# Manually parse json data according to kendo model

Tags: json, parsing, data-binding, model, kendo-ui

Any built-in ready-to-use solution in Kendo UI to parse JSON data according to `schema.model`? 
Maybe something like `kendo.parseData(json, model)`, which will return array of objects?

Comment: do you mean json text to javascript object?

Comment: Yes, but according to some model, where declared field names, types and other metadata,

Comment: I'm doing smth like this now manually, but ready-to-go solution will be much more better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for something like that and couldn't find anything built-in. However, using `Model.set` apparently uses each field's parse logic, so I ended up writing this function which works pretty good:

```
function parse(model, json) {
    // I initialize the model with the json data as a quick fix since
    // setting the id field doesn't seem to work. 
    var parsed = new model(json);
    var fields = Object.keys(model.fields);
    for (var i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
        parsed.set(fields[i], json[fields[i]]);
    }
    return parsed;
}
```

Where `model` is the `kendo.data.Model` definition (or simply `datasource.schema.model`), and `json` is the raw object. Using or modifying it to accept and return arrays shouldn't be too hard, but for my use case I only needed a single object to be parsed at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I actually saw your post the day you posted it but did not have the answer. I just needed to solve this problem myself as part of a refactoring. My solution is for DataSources, not for models directly.

```
kendo.data.DataSource.prototype.parse = function (data) {
    return this.reader.data(data);
    // Note that the original data will be modified. If that is not what you want, change to the following commented line
    // return this.reader.data($.extend({}, data));
}

// ...

someGrid.dataSource.parse(myData);
```

If you want to do it directly with a model, you will need to look at the DataReader class in kendo.data.js and use a similar logic. Unfortunately, the DataReader takes a schema instead of a model and the part dealing with the model is not extracted in it's own method.