# Basic «reflection» in JS

Tags: javascript, json, reflection, model-binding

Can I:

1. Get JS object properties as array?
2. Get property by name (like `obj.prop('propname').val()`)
3. Set property value by name (`obj.prop('propname').val('WAT?')`)
4. Create property by name(`obj.createprop('propname')`).

Why I need this: I have some model declaration (with names, types and in-response ids) and want parse JSON data according to it.

Comment: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/object-reflection-in-javascript.html

Comment: Your other two questions are duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256091/how-to-access-object-property-using-variable - please try to limit yourself to one question per question.

Comment: can you provide sample what you want to do?

Comment: @Quentin, seems, that question can be more specific than in duplicate, if OP provide additional info

Comment: I need it for this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187807/manually-parse-json-data-according-to-kendo-model

Comment: So, I'm visited «original» question, but there's no words about `get` and `set`.

Comment: The fact that a question is duplicate doesn't mean it's identical to yours verbatim, but instead that it asks about and explains the same concept.

Comment: @ArmanHayots js is a very dynamic language, you can create property with simple assign: `a.a = "val"` create property _a_ if it not exist. You need ask more specific question, and also provide what you tried

Comment: I need create property name, which I will know only in runtime. 
Can I create `b` property by `a['b'] = 'val'`?

Comment: @ArmanHayots yep, you can, this is called [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)